# Receive Message from rabbitmq failing to return message in multithreaded environment

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Here is what my application does

1) Client App Send request message with correlationId on REQUEST_QUEUE_1 and waits for the response message on RESPONSE_QUEUE_1 using correlationId

2) Server App receives message from REQUEST_QUEUE_1

3) Server App processes message received in step 2

4) Server App sends response on RESPONSE_QUEUE_1 asynchronously with correlationId received as part of message from step 2.

5) Client App's thread from step 1 receives the response from RESPONSE_QUEUE_1 for correlationId

Here is code snippet of java program doing the sendMessage and receiveMessage to and from the queue on both client and server side - https://gist.github.com/graj2014/f580b35579bf8a94029d.

This code works fine when tested in single request to Client App using jmeter. However multiple user request simultaneously is leaving some of the messages in unacknowledged state and corresponding responses to Client getting timedout.

There is a problem in receiveMessage method with a msgCorrelationId, which is matched with the message on the queue to acknowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
if (msgCorrelationId.toString().equals(correlationId)) {
        ....
        channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
        break;
}
```

If you receive messages, which has `correlationId`, but it doesn't much to provided one, you just skip them from precess and, of course, lose `acknowledgement` for them.

It isn't clear why you go so hard way to do the `request-reply` pattern, because `RabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive()` does the stuff on the matter.

Please, refere to [Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#request-reply) and [test-case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/JavaConfigFixedReplyQueueTests.java)

Comment: I don't want to acknowlegde them, as they are meant for another thread to consume. So should I call channel.basicNack with requeue true?

Comment: That's correct. And I don't say that you should `ack` them. Right, `basicNack` might help, but you eventually end up with the fact, that the same listener (one of those concurrent, or even each of them) starts to do useless work for uninteresting messages. That's why would be better just rely on `TemporaryReplyQueue` for each message, as it does in the `RabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive()` by default - without `replyQueue`. The root of issue is here, that AMQP doesn't provide `selector` option as it is with JMS.

Comment: I used RabbitTemplate SendAndReceive, it works. However when I am load testing it. I see that response time for concurrent requests increases with number of the concurrency. Lets say with jmeter, 1 user for 1000 iterations, the avg response time is 7 ms. with 2 user for 1000 its taking avg resp. time - 14 ms. How can I improve the response time to become constant with concurrent request.

Comment: Don't you think that you do that `concurrency` within the single Thread ?

Comment: My usecase is that different request are sent from the browser, which triggers the sendAndReceive. So don't understand how a single thread can be used for sendAndReceive.